# Events with multiple dates do I use has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Users can create multiple day events.

So an event can have multiple dates, including a start time and end time for the date.

So an event might have these dates:

July 1 2013 9:00am - 5:00pm
July 2 2013 10:00am - 6:00pm
July 7 2013 1:00pm - 5:30pm

So the event table would store the event id, event name, the type of event, address fields for where the event will be held, etc. But how do I model the multiple dates for the event? I could have a separate event_dates table, and that table would have multiple rows for each event:

id        event_date      event_start_time     event_end_time
event1    July 1 2013     9:00am               5:00pm
event1    July 2 2013     10:00am              6:00pm
event1    July 7 2013     1:00pm               5:30pm

But I would also like to query for events occurring on a day (regardless of time), so users could find events in their area that occur on certain days (they might visit multiple events that day).

So how would I model this? Would I use has_and_belongs_to_many, where one event has multiple dates, and one date has multiple events?

In the view, when saving the event, I guess I need to save the event data to the events table, and also save the date/time combination to the other table. But to save the date/time combination to the other table, I need the id for the event that was just saved. So in one form I have a dependency such that the first save must succeed (save event), for the second save to proceed (save date/time using new event id).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set up `Event` to have many `Sessions`. Then each session can specify a date/time range for that session.

As far as querying for a particular day goes, you can use a join and a little Rails magic like so: (assuming rails 3.2)

```
class Event
  has_many :sessions

  def self.on_day(date)
    joins(:sessions).where("session.start < ? AND session.end > ?", date.end_of_day, date.beginning_of_day)
  end
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I would create the sessions for an event in a form? The form would have multiple JQuery datepicker fields, and corresponding custom time picker fields. But the event need to be saved first to populate the corresponding date sessions event_id values>

Comment: I'm also wondering how to query if user searches for events whose date is between a range, say June 20 - June 23? Also what if they are looking for events between certain times on days?

Comment: @GregLafrance You would have to alter the arguments to `.where` to reflect those new bounds.

Comment: @GregLafrance As for the form - that is a separate question in itself. Consider opening a new question about your specific issues.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at closure_tree gem (https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) wich allow you to use acts_as_tree and a hierarchy for your events...
Cheers